# Paypal PHP SDK - no price shown at checkout preview

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

I use the follow code in sandbox mode:

```
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');


$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal(10);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setDescription('Bezahl einfach eh')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());

$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl('http://www.bla.com?pay=yes')
    ->setCancelUrl('http://www.bla.com?pay=no');


$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
    ->setPayer($payer)
    ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
    ->setTransactions([$transaction]);
```

But it doesn't show the 10 USD in the checkout preview so I added:

```
$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

// added ==>
$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('One week premium member')
    ->setCurrency('USD')
    ->setPrice(10);


$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

$details = new Details();
$details->setSubtotal(10);
// <== added


$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency('USD')
        ->setTotal(10);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
    ->setItemList($itemList)  // <== added
    ->setDescription('Bezahl einfach eh')
    ->setInvoiceNumber(uniqid());
```

But now I get follow error:

```
exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in
```

etc.

How should I do that right?

ignore: I need to add some text to the question to be able to post it.. sorry for my bad english by the way

Comment: No one know the solution ??